# My attribute does not change with jquery

Tags: jquery, nested-attributes

How come I can't change each **age="number"** with the following code? Am I missing something in my attribute()?

```
<div id="people">
<li age="number">
<span>22</span>
<span>23</span>
<span>24</span>
<span>25</span>
<span>26</span>
</li>

<li age="number">
<span>22</span>
<span>23</span>
<span>24</span>
<span>25</span>
<span>26</span>
</li>

</div>



$("body").on("click", function(){
var x = $("#people").children( function(){
return $(this).find("span:nth-child(4)").text();
});
$("#people li").attr("age", + x);
});
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid, you should wrap the `li` elements with an `ul` / `ol` element.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Show us what you want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. `x` is a jQuery object, so you can't just convert it to a string, and definitely not to a number (with the `+`). Also, I've never seen a function passed to a traversal function. Here's how I'd do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/G2rzr/

```
$("body").on("click", function () {
    $('#people li').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('age', $('span:nth-child(4)', this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. It doesn't change since children look for children, so the result is an object.

```
$("body").on("click", function(){

var x = $("#people span:nth-child(4)").text();
$("#people li").attr("age", + x);
});
```

Comment: The reason I had children in the code because there were multiple <li>

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", function(){
    var newAgeValue = $("#people span:nth-of-type(4)").text();  
    $("#people li").attr("age", newAgeValue);
});
```